# add text to url with form and get method and auto submit

Tags: html, forms, input

I want add `?orderby=popularity` to url in address bar and auto submit onclick,
I write this code and work correctly.
Do you know better way?

```
<form method="get">
  <label for="price">Price</label>
  <input name='orderby' id="price" value="price" type="radio" onclick='this.form.submit();' style="display: none;">
  <br>
  <label for="date">Date</label>
  <input name='orderby' id="date" value="date" type="radio" onclick='this.form.submit();' style="display: none;">
  <br>
  <label for="popularity">Popularity</label>
  <input name='orderby' id="popularity" value="popularity" type="radio" onclick='this.form.submit();' style="display: none;">
  <br>
</form>
```

Comment: Get rid of the form. Use `<a href>` instead of labels.

Comment: Thanks, it's work and very simple...